# C++ Linked Lists with struct

Tags: c++, this, singly-linked-list

I'm new in C++ and I have something to do with a linked list, and I don't know why it doesn't work, need help from a prof :O)

Here's my .h

```
#ifndef UnCube_H
#define UnCube_H

using namespace std;

class ACube{
  public:
         ACube();
         struct Thecube;
  private:
          void PrintList();

  };
#endif
```

My ACube.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ACube.h"


ACube::ACube(){

};
struct Thecube{
   int base;
   int cube;
   Thecube * next ;
};


void ACube::PrintList(){
};
```

and finally my main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "ACube.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ACube * temp;
temp = (ACube*)malloc(sizeof(ACube));
for (int inc=1; inc <=20 ; inc++){

    temp->ACube->nombrebase = inc;
    temp->cube = inc*inc*inc;
}
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Everything was working fine, but when I add these lines :

```
    temp->ACube->nombrebase = inc;
    temp->cube = inc*inc*inc;
```

I add error saying : 
 'class ACube' has no member named 'TheCube' 
 'class ACube' has no member named 'cube'

Can someone help me because I want to create my list and fill the cube with number.
Other thing I want to use THIS. in the print,

Maybe someone can teach me what's wrong and how to do it !

Thanks for any help

Comment: You seem to be more familiar with C. You can start by replacing member "struct Thecube;" with members "ACube* next; int base; int cube;"

Comment: Why do you have semicolons after function definitions? Also, don't use `malloc`(use `new` if you have to, not naked though, should be within a handle class). I suggest you find a beginner's book and start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a struct inside your class.

```
#ifndef UnCube_H
#define UnCube_H

using namespace std;

class ACube{
  public:
    ACube();
    int base;
    int cube;
    ACube * next ;
  private:
          void PrintList();

  };
#endif
```

ACube.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ACube.h"


ACube::ACube(){

};

void ACube::PrintList(){
};
```

Also, this string is wrong:

```
temp->ACube->nombrebase = inc;
```

it should be just:

```
temp->base = inc;
```

Last but not least, this code doesn't create a linked list, because you don't do anything with the ACube::next pointer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll will check that today, and came back with comments. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are so many horrible problems in your code, I suggest you should learn more C++ knowledge before writing linked list.

**1. What is `nombrebase`?**

I think nobody can answer.

**2. You must allocate C++ class by `new` key word instead of `malloc`.**

`new` invokes not only allocation but also class constructor, while `malloc` allocates only.

**3. `Thecube` should been defined inside `ACube`**

Since the code in your main() refers the member `cube` in class `Thecube`, main() must know what it is.

**4. The member `next` in class `ACube` is a pointer which points to what?**

What does a pointer point to without initilization? You should initial it in constructor, and destroy it in destructor.

**5. `temp->ACube`**

`ACube` is a class type, you can access member object, but not a type.

**6. Never using namespace into a header file**

It would make the client of header file has name collision.

**The following is the corrected code. Just no compile error and runtime error, but this is NOT linked list:**

ACube.h

```
#ifndef UnCube_H
#define UnCube_H

class ACube{
public:
    struct Thecube
    {
        int base;
        int cube;
        Thecube * next;
    };


    ACube();
    ~ACube();
    Thecube *next;

private:
    void PrintList();

};
#endif
```

ACube.cpp

```
ACube::ACube()
: next(new Thecube)
{

}

ACube::~ACube()
{
    delete next;
}

void ACube::PrintList(){
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "ACube.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ACube * temp;
    temp = new ACube;
    for (int inc = 1; inc <= 20; inc++)
    {
        temp->next->base = inc;  // <-- This is not linked list, you shall modify.
        temp->next->cube = inc*inc*inc;  // <-- This is not linked list, you shall modify.
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation seems good to me. I'll will came back later with my analysis. thanks.

Comment: thanks for your help. You said : temp->next->base = inc;  // <-- This is not linked list, you shall modify. So How I can create a linked list ? I'm learning C++ and I have an exercise asking to create that, but we don't saw a way to create Linked List, And I try by myself to find a solution . I know that I need a field for data and a field for the Next pointer, but How I can create my Linked List ? thanks

Comment: The code you wrote is to assign inc and inc*inc*inc to same targets in loop. I think that in your purpose of using a loop is to assign to 20 different nodes of linked list. That's another story how to code linked list. The biggest problem in your code is you're not good at C++ now, you should learn C++ before coding linked list.